# How to decrease the AWS Windows EBS root volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I need to reduce my **Windows EBS root volume**.

We are able to increase the root volume by using AWS Console. So I have followed some document to decrease my Windows EBS root volume:

- I created a new 30GB volume and attached it to my existing instance
- I then used `xcopy` to copy the data from C:\ to D:\ which is newly attached volume
- After completion of copying data, I then stopped the instance and detached both the EBS root volume and the newly added volume.
- Then I reattached the newly created volume to the stopped EC2 instance as `/dev/sda1`

Now I am trying to start my Windows EC2 instance, but it fails to start. It is coming again and again to stopped state.

Note: I received error message like `Sharing Violation` after data copied.

Comment: I think the problem is that a bootable Windows volume contains more than just files. It also contains a boot block and magical stuff that Windows uses to boot-up. This process _might_ handle the requirement better: [Decreasing Root Disk Size of an “EBS Boot” AMI on EC2](https://serverfault.com/a/332884)

Comment: Hi John, Is applicable for Windows EBS root volume? I couldn't find valid document to do.